# Filter Contents on Screen Javascript drop down menu

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code which successfully filters the items on screen depending on what the drop down menu selection is (for example, if the user selects "1" in the menu, then the other operators with the value 2, 3, 4 and 5 are hidden and therefore only operators with "1" are on screen).

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of checking the selection and then hiding the appropriate elements other than using if statements? It has to be in pure javascript.

```
const filter = document.getElementById("selectDropDwn");

 /**
 * Filters operators and only shows the ones which have the same class that has been chosen in the
 * drop-down menu.
 */
function filterOp() {
  showAllOps();
  let option = filter.value;

  if (option === "attacker") {
    hideOperator(opDefend);
  } else if (option === "defender") {
    hideOperator(opAttack);
  } else if (option === "original") {
    hideOperator(opYear1);
    hideOperator(opYear2);
    hideOperator(opYear3);
    hideOperator(opYear4);
    hideOperator(opYear5);
  } else if (option === "1") {
    hideOperator(opOriginal);
    hideOperator(opYear2);
    hideOperator(opYear3);
    hideOperator(opYear4);
    hideOperator(opYear5);
  } else if (option === "2") {
    hideOperator(opOriginal);
    hideOperator(opYear1);
    hideOperator(opYear3);
    hideOperator(opYear4);
    hideOperator(opYear5);
  } else if (option === "3") {
    hideOperator(opOriginal);
    hideOperator(opYear1);
    hideOperator(opYear2);
    hideOperator(opYear4);
    hideOperator(opYear5);
  } else if (option === "4") {
    hideOperator(opOriginal);
    hideOperator(opYear1);
    hideOperator(opYear2);
    hideOperator(opYear3);
    hideOperator(opYear5);
  } else if (option === "5") {
    hideOperator(opOriginal);
    hideOperator(opYear1);
    hideOperator(opYear2);
    hideOperator(opYear3);
    hideOperator(opYear4);
  } else {
    showAllOps();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shorter version of your function :

```js
showAllOps();
let option = filter.value;

let options = {
    original: opOriginal,
    1: opYear1,
    2: opYear2,
    3: opYear3,
    4: opYear4,
    5: opYear5,
}

if(option === "attacker") return hideOperator(opDefend);
else if(option === "defender") return hideOperator(opAttack);


if(Object.keys(options).includes(option)){
    for(const key in options){
        if(key == option) continue;
        hideOperator(options[key]);
    }    
}
```